# Is there a way to run the Macpup 550 Distro on a Raspberry Pi (E.g. Raspberry Pi Zero)?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install The Macpup 550 Linux Distro to a Raspberry Pi Zero if possible, I only have access to a mac computer with no optical drive, it will not boot macpup from a live USB. Writing the Macpup liveCD iso to an SD card does not boot it on a raspberry pi Please help, Beginner here who has only tested a few OS's on a Raspberry Pi.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I found this website but not sure if I can use the instructions to work for the Macpup 550 Distribution if it has been installed on an SD card. Here it is:

https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/convert-retropie-sd-card-image-to-noobs-image

Another website uses similar steps but is slightly different it is in the how to create custom os part of the webpage. here it is:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#how-to-create-a-custom-os-version

Comment: Not sure why this properly formulated question got downvoted ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Macpup is based on [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com/), it is intended for 32 or 64 bit x86 computers. The Raspberry Pi Zero is an ARMv6 computer, and has a completely different architecture than x86. Unless you find a way to compile the entire install to ARMv6 you cannot run Macpup OS on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thought it wouldn't be easy lol, Thank you for the reply, Is there a Operating System that is built for the raspberry pi that is as nimble and quick as macpup with a GUI?. I cannot use PiCore as i cannot install any packages as it does not come with wifi which is all a Pi Zero can use as i do not have a usb Ethernet connection.

Comment: Do you possibly have any info on whether or not I could compile it to for an ARMv6 Processor? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely *must* run Puppy Linux, there's a version for the Raspberry Pi 2 & 3: [Quirky Linux 8.1 for Raspberry Pi2 and Pi3](http://barryk.org/news/?viewDetailed=00441). But I can't recommend running it at *all*: it defaults to running everything as root, which is about the worst idea ever.

Comment: Hi thankyou for the reply, I wanted to run macpup on a Pi Zero as that is the model I have. I see that it is not compatible due to the previous comment. I am after an OS that is as zippy and elegant as Macpup, as I have a fair bit of experience with macpup it was a long shot hope lol.